# How to get the first character of a string

Tags: java, string

I'm sending a request to a server i've put online - When i received an answer, i'm saving it as a String.

Now the thing is that when i've tested the code as a localhost all went fine. 
So let's say a user signed up and the process went fine then the server has retrun the figure 1.

But when i've put it online i'm getting the next String -

```
1<!-- www.serversfree.com Analytics Code --><script src="http://www.serversfree.com"></script><noscript><a title="Free hosting servers" href="http://www.serversfree.com">Free servers</a><a title="Free websites hosting server" href="http://www.serversfree.com">Free websites hosting server</a><a title="Free hosting server features" href="http://www.serversfree.com/server-features/">Free server features</a><a title="Free hosting" href="http://www.bugs3.com">Free hosting</a><a title="Page rank" href="http://www.1pagerank.com">Page rank</a></noscript><script type="text/javascript">  var _gaq = _gaq || [];  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24425628-3']);  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', window.location.host]);  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  (function() {    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);  })();</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bugs3.com/ganalytics.js"></script><!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

And all i want is to know what's the figure at the start of the returning answer - and in the code i've putted here is the number 1.

So my questions is, how can i "cut" the rest of the answer string and just leave the 1?
Of course i prefer that the cutting will be done at the android code, after i'm reciving the answer.

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

If you want a String you can use :

```
res = res.substring(0,1);
```

But if you want a char, you can use :

```
char character = res.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem very well, but if you want to take a part of a String, the [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found it out -

```
String result = 1<---somthing---><---someting-->;

 result = result.substring(0,1);

 //Meaning now  - result = 1;
```

Comment: Use result.charAt(0) if you want to get character

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Moscow";
System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
```

Prints 'M'.